# Search on email domains using the Have I Been Pwned API?

Tags: have-i-been-pwned

Using the HIBP API, is it possible to search for email domains? I know that HIBP has around 5 billion email records. All I want is a count of gmail.com or yahoo.com records.

I know that I can check my own email id and it seems my email id has endured around seven data breaches. I did check out on my own using the Python API, but when I use the string wildcard `*`, the API returns an empty result.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this. You can only get all breaches for an entire e-mail.
If you want to get all e-mails from eg. Gmail you can download some breaches and just grep it.